# How to set up Android's MockContentProvider

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, android-testing

I'm currently testing Android's ContentProvider and running into some issues mocking it. I've already spent days on the internet but didn't find any useful examples except of the introduction on the [Android Developer Site](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/contentprovider_testing.html).

I implemented a ContentProvider and wrote some tests. Everything works here completely fine.  The result of the tests are matching my expectations.

```
public class DirectMessageProviderTest extends ProviderTestCase2<DirectMessageProvider>{

    @SmallTest
    public void testInsert() {
        Log.d(TAG, "testInsert");

        /*
         * result retrieves twitterId for the newly inserted item
         */
        Uri result = provider.insert(
                DirectMessageProvider.CONTENT_URI, 
                createContentValues());

        Log.i(TAG, "INSERT; id for newly inserted item: " + result);

        assertNotNull("INSERT!!! failed", result);

        if (result != null) {
            isDirectMessageInserted = true;
        }
    }

    @SmallTest
    public void testQuery() {
        Log.d(TAG, "testQuery");

        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                DirectMessageProvider.CONTENT_URI, 
                String.valueOf(directMessage.getTwitterId()));

        /*
         * result retrieves a cursor or null
         */
        Cursor result = provider.query(
                uri, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null);

        Log.i(TAG, "QUERY; number of rows inside the cursor: " + result.getCount());

        int expected = isDirectMessageInserted ? 1 : 0;

        assertEquals("QUERY!!! failed", expected, result.getCount());
    }
}
```

I also implemented a class which capsules the ContentProvider and provides more complex methods than delete, insert, query and update. Take a look!

```
public class DirectMessageDataAccessImpl implements
        DirectMessageDataAccessInterface {

    @Override
    public boolean isStored(TwitterDirectMessage directMessage)
            throws DataAccessException {
        Log.d(TAG, "isStored");

        try {
            Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                    DirectMessageProvider.CONTENT_URI, 
                    String.valueOf(directMessage.getTwitterId()));

            Cursor cursor = resolver.query(
                    uri, 
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null);

            cursor.moveToFirst();

            boolean result = (cursor.getCount() > 0 ? true: false);

            cursor.close();

            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new DataAccessException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Finally we`re coming to my problem writing a test for this class. I want to write independent tests for this class using a mocked ContentResolver. I've found this [example] (http://www.androidadb.com/source/npr-android-app-read-only/Npr_Test/src/org/npr/android/util/PlaylistProviderTest.java.html) on the internet and tried to use MockContentResolver.

First of all, I created a new ContentProvider which will retrieve the delete, insert, query and update calls from the tested class, to create the same answer again and again.

```
public class DirectMessageDataAccessTest extends ProviderTestCase2<DirectMessageProvider>{

    private ContentProvider provider = new ContentProvider() {

        @Override
        public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
                String[] selectionArgs) {
            Log.d(TAG, "update");
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
                String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
            Log.w(TAG, "query");
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreate() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
            Log.d(TAG, "insert");
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String getType(Uri uri) {
            Log.d(TAG, "getType");
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
            Log.d(TAG, "delete");
            return 0;
        }
    };
}
```

After this, I modified my setUp Method in order to create a MockContentResolver and added my ContentProvider above

```
@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();

    /*
     * MockContentResolver overrides Android's normal way of resolving providers by authority
     */
    MockContentResolver resolver = new MockContentResolver();

    /*
     * Adds access to a provider based on its authority
     */
    resolver.addProvider(DirectMessageProvider.AUTHORITY, provider);        

    context = new IsolatedContext(resolver, getContext());

    this.setContext(context);
}
```

Last but not least, I wrote a test case for my isStored Method.

```
public void testIsStored() {
    Log.d(TAG, "testIsStored");

    TwitterDirectMessage directMessage = new TwitterDirectMessage();

    directMessage.setTwitterId(123456);

    DirectMessageDataAccessInterface dataAccess = 
            new DirectMessageDataAccessImpl(context);

    try {
        assertFalse(dataAccess.isStored(directMessage));
    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        fail("...");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, android.content.ContentProvider always throws a NullPointerException. I'm calling `resolver.query(...)`in line 72 of DirectMessageDataAccessImpl

```
E/DirectMessageDataAccessImpl(1758): null
E/DirectMessageDataAccessImpl(1758): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/DirectMessageDataAccessImpl(1758):    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:284)
E/DirectMessageDataAccessImpl(1758):    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:177)
E/DirectMessageDataAccessImpl(1758):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:311)
E/DirectMessageDataAccessImpl(1758):    at xxx.xxxxx.xxxxxxx.app.database.dataaccess.implementation.DirectMessageDataAccessImpl.isStored(DirectMessageDataAccessImpl.java:72)
E/DirectMessageDataAccessImpl(1758):    at xxx.xxxxx.xxxxxxx.app.test.dataaccess.DirectMessageDataAccessTest.testIsStored(DirectMessageDataAccessTest.java:107)
```

Answer (score 0):

In constructor you should set

```
public YourClass() {
    super(DBProvider.class, "com.yourpackage.main");// class of Your Content provider and application package
}
```

and then just call

```
MockContentResolver mockContentResolver = getMockContentResolver();
assertNotNull(mockContentResolver);
```

in a tests

Comment: Is there any way to inject my own provider in order to get static results? As soon as I'm adding 'addProvider', I get the NullPointerException above.

Comment: You adding your own provider here ->  super(DBProvider.class, "com.yourpackage.main"); MockContentResolver will keep reference to your provider